# How to encode fetched data from MySQL to JSON via PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json

I'm trying to encode data coming from Mysql database into JSON format via PHP.Here's the code segment:

```
try
{
    $statement = $db->prepare($query);
    $result = $statement->execute($query_params);

    $rows = $statement->fetchAll();

    echo print_r($rows)."<br/>";

    foreach($rows as $row)
    {
        foreach($row as $a)
    {
        $studentInfo = array();
        $studentInfo["course"] = $a["coursename"];
        $studentInfo["grade"] = $a["grade"];
        array_push($response['info'], $studentInfo);
    }
    }
    echo json_encode($response);
}
```

But I'm not able to encode this array into JSON.
The `print_r($rows)` prints the following:

```
Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [id] => 22222
        [coursename] => sp1
        [grade] => B
    )
    [1] => Array (
        [id] => 22222
        [coursename] => sw1
        [grade] => A-
    )
    [2] => Array (
        [id] => 22222
        [coursename] => sw2
        [grade] => B+
    )
)
1
```

And echo `json_encode($response)` prints the following:

```
{"info":null}
```

Could anyone please show me how to parse this array into JSON?
I would like to get to each course and its grade in JSON format.

Comment: Remove the inner loop. `$row` has the contents you are looking for instead of `$a`

Comment: or just `json_encode(array('info'=>$rows))` from your original `$rows` ... no need for *any* of the loops..

Comment: Thanks datasage. Removing the inner loop solved the porblem!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
try
{
    $statement = $db->prepare($query);
    $result = $statement->execute($query_params);

    $rows = $statement->fetchAll();

    echo print_r($rows)."<br/>";

    $response=array();
    $info=array();

    foreach($rows as $row)
    {      
        $studentInfo = array();
        $studentInfo["id"]=$row["id"];
        $studentInfo["course"] = $row["coursename"];
        $studentInfo["grade"] = $row["grade"];
        array_push($info, $studentInfo);    
    }

    $response['info']=$info;
    echo json_encode($response); // or echo json_encode($info);// whatever you want
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd do something like this:

```
try {
    $statement = $db->prepare($query);
    $result = $statement->execute($query_params);
    if($result) {
        $arr = Array();
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $arr[] = $row;
        }
     echo json_encode($arr);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

json_encode() can directly encode the array.

at your code line 8, can do this

```
echo json_encode($rows);
```

Please click here to refer for more info
http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

```
<?php
$arr = array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3, 'd' => 4, 'e' => 5);

echo json_encode($arr);
?>
```

Output:
{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}